# adding json element in json file

Tags: json, cordova

I have a json file in my android local device, im able to read and edit the json file and store json data in it.
But the problem is arising when i want to insert new element in the json file. Im able to change the value of existing variables.
the json file data is:

```
var data = {items: 
{id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"}
};
```

i want to add one more element to it so that json file will look like

```
var data = {items: [
{id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"},
{id: "7", name: "Douglas Adams", type: "comedy"}
};
```

i tried with

```
data.items.push{id: "7", name: "Douglas Adams", type: "comedy"}
```

but its not working.

im creating android app using phonegap framework with telerik IDE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
data.items.push(
    {id: "7", name: "Douglas Adams", type: "comedy"}
);
```

You are missing `()`

Your first file example is missing `[]`

Check out this links to know more about json addition and removal
[Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object) , [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4538269/adding-removing-items-from-json-data-with-jquery)