# Adding an element to JSON notation using Javascript objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, javascript-objects

I wish to add wishlist functionality to a client site using a combination of Javascript and cookies. To achieve this, each item on the site will have a button that the user can click to add the item to their wishlist. The button code is as follows:

```
<a data-id="5054" data-node="3286" data-type="package" class="wishList">Add to Wishlist</a>
```

When the button is clicked the following JavaScript is executed:

```
$('.wishList').click(function () {
    var nodeId = $(this).data("node");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var type = $(this).data("type");

    var package = new Object();
    package.id = id;
    package.nodeId = nodeId;

    var jsonObject = new Object();    
    jsonObject.package = package;


    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    console.log(jsonString);

    var newObject = new Object();
    newObject.id = 8888;
    newObject.nodeId = 7777;

    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    obj['package'].push(newObject);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

This code is derived from this Stack Overflow question and my own knowledge:

[Adding a new array element to a JSON object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object)

The aim of the code is to simulate both creating a new JSON notation using Javascript objects as well as parsing the notation back into a Javascript object, adding a new item to the array and then using stringify to convert it back into a string again. My problem is, the push method does not seem to work. When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
TypeError: obj.package.push is not a function
```

As this part of the code was taken from the other question, I am at a loss to understand why it is not working in this context as I do not see any comments suggesting that this does not work on the other post.

My aim is to build up the following JSON notation:

```
{"package":[{"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},{"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"}]}
```

This will eventually lead to a more complex notation of:

```
{"package":[{"id":"5054","nodeId":"3286"},{"id":"8888","nodeId":"7777"}], "hotel":[{"id":"3421","nodeId":"1234"},{"id":"8748","nodeId":"2435"}],}
```

This notation will then be stored as a cookie that will be added to and manipulated using JavaScript and read on the server side with each request using .Net.

My question is, what am I doing wrong here? Why in this case is the .push funcionality not working?

I've created a Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/jezzipin/kdVVK/

Comment: `new Object()` → `{}`

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString); This does not mean obj is now an array. '.push' only pushes on JS arrays. What console.log tells you about 'obj'? In case 'obj' is an object, it's more like: obj.package = {}; obj.package = newObject;

Comment: @Bonatoc obj.package.push is not a function. Could you elaborate? It's late here and I don't quite follow.

Comment: You can't use 'push' on objects. 'push' is for arrays. What does 'console.log(obj);' show in Chrome Dev Tools (or FF Firebug, whatever you use as a console)?

Comment: Then how come it was used in the other answer? I see no difference in the methodology I am using. I merely wish to add another set of records to an existing JSON notation. Using obj.package = {}; obj.package = newObject; overwrites the previous record.

Comment: In the linked example 'theTeam' is an array (note the square brackets)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As your package property will be a simple list of objects, it needs to be an array.

```
$('.wishList').click(function () {
    var nodeId = $(this).data("node");
    var id = $(this).data("id");
    var type = $(this).data("type");

    var package = [];

    package.push({
        id: id,
        nodeId: nodeId
    });

    var jsonObject = {};    
    jsonObject.package = package;


    var jsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);
    console.log(jsonString);

    var newObject = {
        id: 8888,
        nodeId: 7777
    };

    var obj = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    obj['package'].push(newObject);
    console.log(JSON.stringify(obj));
});
```

[updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kdVVK/1/)

Comment: @jezzipin — My point exactly (going to delete my answer). You can add objects to arrays, and vice-versa. You just need to be careful in your construction and declare your "containers" types ("object" or "array") properly from the start.

Comment: @dc5 You sir are a gentleman and a scholar thanks a lot for this :-)