# how to add or insert record in json file

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

how can i add or insert record(in a form of array) in my json file using php or javascript?

i've tried this one but no luck:

```
$file = file_get_contents('Copy.json');
            $tempArray = json_decode($file);

            $arr = array('type' => 'Feature',
                        'id'=>$adsID,
                        'properties' => array(
                        'IMAGE'=>$ALogo,
                        'NAME'=>$name,
                        'TEL'=>$ATel,
                        'URL'=>$url,
                        'ADRESS1'=>$A_add,
                        'ADDRESS2'=>'add2',
                        'CITY'=>'Angeles City',
                        'ZIP'=>'2009'),
                            'geometry' => array(
                            'type' => 'Point',
                            'coordinates' => array ($ACoords1))
                        ) ;// features


            echo json_encode($arr);//$data[] = $_POST['data'];

            array_push($tempArray, $arr);
            $jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);
            file_put_contents('Copy.json', $jsonData);
```

Comment: what's wrong with this code anyway?

Comment: This can help you  http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/file/dndfiles/

Comment: when i run this code there is an error in using the array_push, i just want to new record in my json file

Comment: possible duplicate of [Adding a new array element to a JSON object](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object)

Answer (score 1):

array merge
$file = file_get_contents('Copy.json');
            $tempArray = json_decode($file);

```
        $arr = array('type' => 'Feature',
                    'id'=>$adsID,
                    'properties' => array(
                    'IMAGE'=>$ALogo,
                    'NAME'=>$name,
                    'TEL'=>$ATel,
                    'URL'=>$url,
                    'ADRESS1'=>$A_add,
                    'ADDRESS2'=>'add2',
                    'CITY'=>'Angeles City',
                    'ZIP'=>'2009'),
                        'geometry' => array(
                        'type' => 'Point',
                        'coordinates' => array ($ACoords1))
                    ) ;// features


        echo json_encode($arr);//$data[] = $_POST['data'];

        $merge = array_merge($tempArray, $arr);
        $jsonData = json_encode($merge);
        file_put_contents('Copy.json', $jsonData);
```