# Add object to JSON file before ]

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

It's probably something ridiculous I'm missing out, but when I add an `object` to my `json` file with `NodeJs` it adds it (obviously?) at the end of the file and so after `]`

```
var file = './data/questions.json';    
fs.appendFile(file, ', ' + JSON.stringify(req.body), function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

result is something like this:

```
[
{'id':1, 'name':'Tom'}
], {'id':2, 'name':'Jerry'}
```

Comment: The result seems to be good for me. Do you have the full code?

Comment: You would be better off parsing the JSON, modifying the object and then restringing it.

Comment: Is there a reason why I'm getting down voted here?

Comment: It's doing exactly what you are asking it to. You need to actually parse the js, add the object, then stringify it again and save it to the file.

Comment: Obviously it's doing what I tell it to do, that's why I'm here: to ask what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object

Comment: @Greg Please show more code. What is the input (`req.body`)?

Comment: @MarcoAlka Judging by the result `req.body` is `{'id':2, 'name':'Jerry'}`

Comment: The one that is added after `]`obviously. I wouldn't worry about the `req.body`  it's a valid `object` that is added to the `JSON` file but at the wrong place

Comment: @Greg Does my *pseudo* code help you to any extent?

Comment: @PraveenKumar I'm trying at the moment, I'll give update in a sec

Comment: @Greg Any good news?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the file already has an array in it already, what you need is:

```
var file = './data/questions.json';
// get the contents of the file
var fileContents = do_something_to_get_contents;
// convert to js object
fileContents = JSON.parse(fileContents);
// push the array
fileContents = fileContents.push(req.body);
// update the file contents by stringify
fs.replaceFile(file, JSON.stringify(fileContents), function (err) {
    console.log(err);
});
```

I am not so good in Node JS. So I am assuming the following:

1. `do_something_to_get_contents` gets the file contents.
2. `replaceFile` Replace this with a function that writes fresh contents to the file.

Comment: I think it's fine that you're not good with node.js if the OP didn't have any node code.

Comment: @Blubberguy22 Thanks buddy... `:)`

Comment: @Greg Did you just copy and paste?

Comment: I did most of the parts, except where I had to "do something"

Comment: @Greg `fs.replaceFile` is pseudo too! Kindly replace that with the real function...

Comment: You're not 'so good in Node Js' yet give me a solution full of pseudos. I'm as new to Node as you so how should I know what's right and wrong.

Comment: @Greg You must read the **two points** that say: `So I am assuming the following:` It clearly mentions: `do_something_to_get_contents` and `replaceFile` are pseudo codes!!! Can't you even understand that?

Comment: To me that reads: "replaceFile: the function that writes contents to the file"

Comment: @Greg Really sorry. I will update it to make it clear.

Comment: @Greg Any positive news? Updates?

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse the JSON file to add to it. Try something like this:

```
var file = './data/questions.json';
var fileData = get_data_from_file
var jData = JSON.parse(file);
jData.push({'id':2, 'name':'Jerry'});
var newFileData = JSON.stringify(jData);
//put the data back into the file
```

Comment: Er, no. `JSON.parse(file)` will attempt to parse `./data/questions.json`, not the **contents** of the file. You'll need to read it first. And I guess the OP also wants the resulting JSON-encoded data to be written to a file.

Comment: @jcaron Good point, my bad, I didn't notice that. I'll fix it, thanks.