# Find node by id in json tree

Tags: javascript, json, javascript-objects

I want to add the `children` array to node where `id = 52126f7d` (or another). How do I do it?

```
var children = [
  { name: 'great-granchild3',
    id: '2a12a10h'
  },
  { name: 'great-granchild4',
    id: 'bpme7qw0'
  }
]

// json tree
var objects = {
  name: 'all objects',
  id:"2e6ca1c3",      
  children: [
     {
         name: 'child',
         id: "6c03cfbe",
         children: [                 
             { name: 'grandchild1',
               id: "2790f59c"
             },
             { name: 'grandchild2',
               id: "52126f7d"
             },
             { name: 'grandchild3',
               id: "b402f14b" 
             },
             {
               name: 'grandchild4',
               id: "6c03cff0",
               children: [
                 { name: 'great-grandchild1',
                   id: "ce90ffa6"
                 },
                 { name: 'great-grandchild2',
                   id: "52f95f28" 
                 }
              ]
            }
         ]
    },        
     {
       name: 'child2',
       id: "7693b310",
       children: [
          { name: 'grandchild5',
            id: "def86ecc"  
          },
          { name: 'grandchild6',
            id: "6224a8f8"
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
}
```

to end up with

```
var objects = {
  name: 'all objects',
  id:"2e6ca1c3",      
  children: [
     {
         name: 'child',
         id: "6c03cfbe",
         children: [                 
             { name: 'grandchild1',
               id: "2790f59c"
             },
             { name: 'grandchild2',
               id: "52126f7d",
               children = [
                 { name: 'great-granchild3',
                   id: '2a12a10h'
                 },
                 { name: 'great-granchild4',
                   id: 'bpme7qw0'
                 }
               ]
             },
             { name: 'grandchild3',
               id: "b402f14b" 
             },
             {
               name: 'grandchild4',
               id: "6c03cff0",
               children: [
                 { name: 'great-grandchild1',
                   id: "ce90ffa6"
                 },
                 { name: 'great-grandchild2',
                   id: "52f95f28" 
                 }
              ]
            }
         ]
    },        
     {
       name: 'child2',
       id: "7693b310",
       children: [
          { name: 'grandchild5',
            id: "def86ecc"  
          },
          { name: 'grandchild6',
            id: "6224a8f8"
          }
       ]
    }
 ]
}
```

Comment: possible duplidate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object

Answer (score 8, accepted):

by finding the proper node first.

```
function getNodeById(id, node){
    var reduce = [].reduce;
    function runner(result, node){
        if(result || !node) return result;
        return node.id === id && node || //is this the proper node?
            runner(null, node.children) || //process this nodes children
            reduce.call(Object(node), runner, result);  //maybe this is some ArrayLike Structure
    }
    return runner(null, node);
}

var target = getNodeById("52126f7d", objects);
target.children = children;
```

Comment: target is separate variable. how to insert `target` in existing `objects`?

Comment: you don't have to insert it, it is a reference to the particular node with that id. This node already is in objects.

Comment: i want to get a full tree with `target` nodes. I edited question, please look again.

Comment: did you even try to execute my example? It seems to me that you lack an understanding of such basic concepts like what are Variables, Objects  and References. Pls try to execute my example and then tell me that it didn't work, what result you got, and what you expected.

Comment: sorry, it was my mistake... in my function `addChildren(children, parent_id){ var target = this.getNodeById(parent_id, objectsList); target.children = children; return objectsList; }` I returned `target` :(

Comment: Beware, getNodeById() may return null, if it doesn't find a matching node, then your function will break, cause you don't handle this case.

Answer (score -6):

How about:

```
objects.children[0].children[1].children = children;
```