# Karate Framework - How to inject array to a JSON key in the payload?

Tags: json, karate

I am trying to inject array (values) to a json key `propertyBatch`, and this key will have multiple array elements as values, see below -`payload` ex:

```
{
  "fname": "value1",
  "propertyBatch":
    [ 
      {
      "propId": 11,
      "subPropId": {
                    "id": [
                            "4234"
                          ]
                   }
      },
      {
      "propId": 12,
      "subPropId": {
                    "id": [
                           "4235"
                          ]
                   }
      }
    ]
}
```

In a scenario, I will have a payload like the above and then I like to inject json to the -`propertyBatch`. To be more specific, Assume that in first occasion it may have propertyBatch of length 1, meaning it has one json value, and in second run -`propertyBatch` might have 2 or 3 values and the length can be 2 or 3 based on number of json values injection. As shown in above `payload`, I have `propertyBatch` with length `2` because it has two json values.

I want to achieve this, and I thinking my scenario be `Scenario Outline:` with `Examples` , and examples will have json values to replace or inject key - `propertyBatch`

Note, I tried various examples and variety of approaches that are explained in the following links. And also implemented java code using `javax.Json` library, but the return value is a String or array, and I am not able to succeed or solve my objective.

[Karate](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/demos/js-arrays.feature)

[stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884840/adding-a-new-array-element-to-a-json-object)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded expressions can be used:

```
* def baz = [1, 2]
* def foo = { bar: 1, baz: '#(baz)' }
* match foo == { bar: 1, baz: [1, 2] }

* def baz = [3]
* def foo = { bar: 1, baz: '#(baz)' }
* match foo == { bar: 1, baz: [3] }
```